# How to query in solrNet

Tags: c#, apache, solr, solrnet

I am new to solrnet . i need to Pass this url to solr to my "pharmaSearch" requestHandler and i need to get the result xml . guide how to do this in solrNet(Now for the url it is working in brower) where else i need to call this from .net application

[http://localhost:9090/solrSDIS/study/pharmaSearch/?&Eq=(A*B*C)&ExpTerm=A,B,C&QueryLevel=2,2,1&q=526:(27747) AND (1028:[10 TO 27]) AND (469:[-10 TO 742]) AND 523:("Body Weights")  AND 262:n , (518:"27058") AND  (430:((Necrosis))) AND 523:("Microscopic Findings")  AND 262:n  ,(169:"7631")&scope=2](http://localhost:9090/solrSDIS/study/pharmaSearch/?&Eq=%28A%2aB%2aC%29&ExpTerm=A,B,C&QueryLevel=2,2,1&q=526%3a%2827747%29%20AND%20%281028%3a%5B10%20TO%2027%5D%29%20AND%20%28469%3a%5B-10%20TO%20742%5D%29%20AND%20523%3a%28%22Body%20Weights%22%29%20%20AND%20262%3an%20,%20%28518%3a%2227058%22%29%20AND%20%20%28430%3a%28%28Necrosis%29%29%29%20AND%20523%3a%28%22Microscopic%20Findings%22%29%20%20AND%20262%3an%20%20,%28169%3a%227631%22%29&scope=2)
Let me know if you need any details ...

Advance Thanks .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass the name of your handler by using the ExtraParams parameter in the QueryOptions as shown in the addition parameters section here:

http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/Querying

```
...
ExtraParams = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
   {"qt", "paramSearch"},
   {"Eq", "(A*B*C)" },
   ...
}
...
```

You can build up a fluent query as shown in the documentation for solrnet here:

http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/DSL

```
... Query.Field("523").Is("Body Weights") && Query.Field("469").From(-10).To(742) && ...
```

The [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/) contains everything you need to compose your query.

Answer (score 2):

You need to read the documentation on the SolrNet Google Code Home Page - http://code.google.com/p/solrnet to learn the basics of using SolrNet so that you can map your solr rest query above to the appropriate SolrNet syntax.

I would suggest starting with the [Basic Usage](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/BasicUsage2) page as this gives a very nice sample of executing a search against solr. Then you can leverage the answer above by @SteadyEddi to call your custom request paraeters.